# S3 policy - user able to list all prefixes and objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wanted the to limit the user to upload and list objects in `dir1` only but it's able to list all the prefixes of the bucket. It can only upload to `dir1` which is desired. How can I modify the policy so that user1 can list and upload objects of `dir1` only?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "HomeDirObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/dir1/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListBucket` command (which shows objects in a bucket) takes a `Condition` like this:

```
  {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
     "Condition":
       "StringLike": {
         "s3:prefix": "dir1/*
       }
  }
```

This will Allow listing the contents of that bucket, but only if the prefix starts with `dir1/`.

See also: [Use IAM policies to grant access to user-specific folders](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-s3-user-specific-folder/)

Comment: Something wrong with the syntax here. Couldn't figure out. There is a missing ending double quotes but another error is still there.

Comment: Ah! I changed it to use `StringLike` since there is a wildcard. Can you try that?

Comment: Yeah that works. The `Condition` needs to be only for `s3:ListBucket` ? I didn't add the condition to `s3:PutObject" or  "s3:GetObject" ` actions and it works.

Comment: That is correct. They take different inputs.